# Java/Android - Gson().fromJson() with Type is still giving an Unchecked cast Warning

Tags: java, android, json, warnings, gson

I use the Gson().fromJson method to convert a JSON-String to a List of my Object (Products). I've heard I need to use a Type as a parameter in the fromJson to prevent getting an Unchecked cast Warning, but I'm still getting it..

Here is my code:

```
List<Product> p = null;
try{
    // Convert JSON-string to a List of Product objects
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Product>>(){}.getType();
    p = (List<Product>)new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
}
catch(JsonParseException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why do I still get the Unchecked cast Warning [Object to List]?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I changed

```
List<Product> p = (List<Product>) new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

to

```
List<Product> p = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

and now I don't have the warning anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use `ObjectMapper` from Jackson API instead of Gson.

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Product>>() {});
```

One reason for suggesting an alternative is because `TypeToken` is still declared as an unstable class.